# Selenium/Java: get index/position of currently selected option in a dropdown menu

Tags: java, select, selenium, indexing, html.dropdownlistfor

How do get the index of the currently selected option in a dropdown menu in Selenium? Getting the text label for it is easy

```
String searchString = select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

It is also easy to select the n-th element

```
select.selectByIndex(25);
```

But I want to know that the currently selected item's index is 25. When I know that I want to log the value and then select next by index.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used the below html code snippet of dropdown:-

```
<select name="Students">
<option value="student1">student1</option>
<option value="student2">student2</option>
<option value="student3">student3</option>
<option value="student4">student4</option>
</select>
```

Below is the code for selecting from the dropdown and then getting the index of the option selected:-

```
    Select sel = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@name='Students']")));

    sel.selectByVisibleText("student4");

    List<WebElement> list = sel.getOptions();

    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
        if(list.get(i).getText().equals(sel.getFirstSelectedOption().getText())){
            System.out.println("The index of the selected option is: "+i);
            break;
            }
    }
```

**Note:-** Output will be "3", as the index starts from "0".

Answer (score 1):

In our Selenium-Tests, a more concise snippet was used:

```
int index = select.getOptions().indexOf(select.getFirstSelectedOption();
```